# Get a recarray view of an ndarray (which may also be a view)

Tags: python, numpy, recarray, structured-array

I'm trying to get a view of 2D ndarray as a record or structured array without copying. This seems to work fine if `a` owns it data

```
>>> a = np.array([[  1, 391,  14,  26],
              [ 17, 371,  15,  30],
              [641, 340,   4,   7]])
>>> b = a.view(zip('abcd',[a.dtype]*4))
array([[(1, 391, 14, 26)],
       [(17, 371, 15, 30)],
       [(641, 340, 4, 7)]], 
      dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<i8'), ('c', '<i8'), ('d', '<i8')])
>>> b.base is a
True
```

But if `a` is already a view, this fails. Here's an example

```
>>> b = a[:,[0,2,1,3]]
>>> b.base is None
False
>>> b.view(zip('abcd',[a.dtype]*4))
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

Interestingly, in this case `b.base` is a transpose of the view

```
>>> (b.base == b.T).all()
True
```

So it makes sense that numpy couldn't create the view of that that I wanted.

However, if I use

```
>>> b = np.take(a,[0,2,1,3],axis=1)
```

This results in `b` being a proper copy of the data so that taking the recarray view works. Side question: Can someone explain this behavior in constrast to fancy indexing?

My question is, am I going about this the wrong way? Is taking a view the way I'm doing it not supported? If so, what would be the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

(big edit)

`b` is `F_CONTINGUOUS` (see `b.flags`).  The number of fields in the view then needs to match the number of rows of `b`, not the number of columns:

```
In [204]: b=a[:,[0,2,1,3]].view('i4,i4,i4')
In [205]: b
Out[205]: 
array([[(0, 4, 8), (2, 6, 10), (1, 5, 9), (3, 7, 11)]], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

A simpler case is `a.copy(order='F').view('i4,i4,i4')`

`np.take(a,[0,2,1,3],axis=1)`  and `a[:,[0,2,1,3]].copy()` produce `C_CONTIGUOUS` copies, and thus can be viewed with 4 fields.

Note also the `b.base` has 3 columns.

---

(earlier stumbling around the issue)

Being a view isn't an issue.

```
 a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
 a.view('i4,i4,i4,i4')
```

does just fine.

Making a copy of the first `b` also works:

```
 b=a[:,[0,2,1,3]].copy()
 b.view('i4,i4,i4,i4')
```

The 1st `b` (without copy) is `F_CONTIGUOUS` (look at `b.flags`). That's what your `b.base == b.T` is showing.

`np.take` produces the same sort of array as that `b` `copy` - i.e. same flags and same `__array_interface__` display.

Other things that work:

```
a[[0,2,1],:].view('i4,i4,i4,i4')
a.T[[0,2,1,3],:].T.view('i4,i4,i4,i4')
```

If I replace the mixed slicing and array indexing with pure array indexing:

```
a[[[0],[1],[2]],[0,2,1,3]].view('i4,i4,i4,i4')
```

the result is `C_CONTIGUOUS`.  So there are details in `[:, [...]]` that I haven't explained - specifically why it produces an `F_CONTIGUOUS` copy.

The mixed basic/advanced indexing doc section does warn that memory layout can change:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing

> In the simplest case, there is only a single advanced index. A single advanced index can for example replace a slice and the result array will be the same, however, it is a copy and may have a different memory layout. A slice is preferable when it is possible.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know memory layout could change like that. To be clear, I knew that indexing like `a[:,[0,2,1,3]` will return a copy, but I didn't know that it could be `F_CONTIGOUS` or that `np.take` will always return a `C_CONTIGUOUS` (the numpy doc says that `np.take` does the same thing as fancy indexing, which seems wrong in this instance). How would you handle getting this particular view (without copy) in a way that always works? Is it bad practice to check whether the array is `F\C_CONTIGOUS`?